# Difficulty with XSLT grouping and summation with fixed XML

Tags: xml, sum, xslt-1.0, grouping

Existing XML:

```
"<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="summary1.xslt"?>
<SYSTEM>
    <XMLfile name="Filename of current XML file">sample1.xml</XMLfile>
    <TestInstance0>
        <LogFile>summary1.log</LogFile>
        <TSVFile/>
        <TesterID>Me</TesterID>
        <Station>DEV01</Station>
        <ReleaseVersion>Rel_I02</ReleaseVersion>
        <StartTime name="Test Execution Start Date and Time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss">20161221:163642</StartTime>
        <EndTime name="Test Execution End Date and Time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss">20161221:174409</EndTime>
        <TotalTime name="Test Execution Total Time HH:mm:ss">1:07:27</TotalTime>
        <AutoTime name="Test Automation Total Time HH:mm:ss">1:07:27</AutoTime>
        <IdleTime name="Test Idle/Wait Total Time HH:mm:ss">0:00:00</IdleTime>
        <Status name="Test Execution Status.  Use IMCOMPLETE,PASS,FAIL">FAIL</Status>
        <TestList>
            <Test1>
                <StartTime name="Start date and time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss.">20161221:163643</StartTime>
                <TotalTime name="Total test time in seconds">0</TotalTime>
                <AutoTime name="Total automation time in seconds">0</AutoTime>
                <IdleTime name="Total idle/wait time in seconds">0</IdleTime>
                <TestResult name="Use INCOMPLETE PASS FAIL SKIP.">PASS</TestResult>
                <FailDesc name="Description of failure">COMPLETE</FailDesc>
            </Test1>
            <Test2>
                <StartTime name="Start date and time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss.">20161221:163643</StartTime>
                <TotalTime name="Total test time in seconds">940</TotalTime>
                <AutoTime name="Total automation time in seconds">940</AutoTime>
                <IdleTime name="Total idle/wait time in seconds">0</IdleTime>
                <TestResult name="Use INCOMPLETE PASS FAIL SKIP.">PASS</TestResult>
                <FailDesc name="Description of failure">COMPLETE</FailDesc>
            </Test2>
            <Test3>
                <StartTime name="Start date and time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss.">20161221:165223</StartTime>
                <TotalTime name="Total test time in seconds">488</TotalTime>
                <AutoTime name="Total automation time in seconds">488</AutoTime>
                <IdleTime name="Total idle/wait time in seconds">0</IdleTime>
                <TestResult name="Use INCOMPLETE PASS FAIL SKIP.">PASS</TestResult>
                <FailDesc name="Description of failure">COMPLETE</FailDesc>
            </Test3>
            <Test4>
                <StartTime name="Start date and time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss.">20161221:170031</StartTime>
                <TotalTime name="Total test time in seconds">1067</TotalTime>
                <AutoTime name="Total automation time in seconds">47</AutoTime>
                <IdleTime name="Total idle/wait time in seconds">1020</IdleTime>
                <TestResult name="Use INCOMPLETE PASS FAIL SKIP.">PASS</TestResult>
                <FailDesc name="Description of failure">COMPLETE</FailDesc>
            </Test4>
            <Test5>
                <StartTime name="Start date and time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss.">20161221:171818</StartTime>
                <TotalTime name="Total test time in seconds">1551</TotalTime>
                <AutoTime name="Total automation time in seconds">1551</AutoTime>
                <IdleTime name="Total idle/wait time in seconds">0</IdleTime>
                <TestResult name="Use INCOMPLETE PASS FAIL SKIP.">FAIL</TestResult>
                <FailDesc name="Description of failure">Failed Test5</FailDesc>
            </Test5>
            <Test6>
                <StartTime name="Start date and time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss."/>
                <TotalTime name="Total test time in seconds"/>
                <AutoTime name="Total automation time in seconds"/>
                <IdleTime name="Total idle/wait time in seconds"/>
                <TestResult name="Use INCOMPLETE PASS FAIL SKIP.">NOT RUN</TestResult>
                <FailDesc name="Description of failure"/>
            </Test6>
            <Test7>
                <StartTime name="Start date and time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss."/>
                <TotalTime name="Total test time in seconds"/>
                <AutoTime name="Total automation time in seconds"/>
                <IdleTime name="Total idle/wait time in seconds"/>
                <TestResult name="Use INCOMPLETE PASS FAIL SKIP.">NOT RUN</TestResult>
                <FailDesc name="Description of failure"/>
            </Test7>
            <Test8>
                <StartTime name="Start date and time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss."/>
                <TotalTime name="Total test time in seconds"/>
                <AutoTime name="Total automation time in seconds"/>
                <IdleTime name="Total idle/wait time in seconds"/>
                <TestResult name="Use INCOMPLETE PASS FAIL SKIP.">NOT RUN</TestResult>
                <FailDesc name="Description of failure"/>
            </Test8>
            <Test9>
                <StartTime name="Start date and time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss."/>
                <TotalTime name="Total test time in seconds"/>
                <AutoTime name="Total automation time in seconds"/>
                <IdleTime name="Total idle/wait time in seconds"/>
                <TestResult name="Use INCOMPLETE PASS FAIL SKIP.">NOT RUN</TestResult>
                <FailDesc name="Description of failure"/>
            </Test9>
            <Test10>
                <StartTime name="Start date and time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss."/>
                <TotalTime name="Total test time in seconds"/>
                <AutoTime name="Total automation time in seconds"/>
                <IdleTime name="Total idle/wait time in seconds"/>
                <TestResult name="Use INCOMPLETE PASS FAIL SKIP.">NOT RUN</TestResult>
                <FailDesc name="Description of failure"/>
            </Test10>
        </TestList>
    </TestInstance0>
    <TestInstance1>
        <LogFile>sample1.log</LogFile>
        <TSVFile/>
        <TesterID>Me</TesterID>
        <Station>DEV01</Station>
        <ReleaseVersion>Rel_I02</ReleaseVersion>
        <StartTime name="Test Execution Start Date and Time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss">20161221:192226</StartTime>
        <EndTime name="Test Execution End Date and Time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss">20161221:194931</EndTime>
        <TotalTime name="Test Execution Total Time HH:mm:ss">0:27:06</TotalTime>
        <AutoTime name="Test Automation Total Time HH:mm:ss">0:27:06</AutoTime>
        <IdleTime name="Test Idle/Wait Total Time HH:mm:ss">0:00:00</IdleTime>
        <Status name="Test Execution Status.  Use IMCOMPLETE,PASS,FAIL">FAIL</Status>
        <TestList>
            <Test1>
                <StartTime name="Start date and time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss.">20161221:192226</StartTime>
                <TotalTime name="Total test time in seconds">0</TotalTime>
                <AutoTime name="Total automation time in seconds">0</AutoTime>
                <IdleTime name="Total idle/wait time in seconds">0</IdleTime>
                <TestResult name="Use INCOMPLETE PASS FAIL SKIP.">PASS</TestResult>
                <FailDesc name="Description of failure">COMPLETE</FailDesc>
            </Test1>
            <Test2>
                <StartTime name="Start date and time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss.">20161221:192227</StartTime>
                <TotalTime name="Total test time in seconds">0</TotalTime>
                <AutoTime name="Total automation time in seconds">0</AutoTime>
                <IdleTime name="Total idle/wait time in seconds">0</IdleTime>
                <TestResult name="Use INCOMPLETE PASS FAIL SKIP.">PASS</TestResult>
                <FailDesc name="Description of failure">COMPLETE</FailDesc>
            </Test2>
            <Test3>
                <StartTime name="Start date and time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss.">20161221:192227</StartTime>
                <TotalTime name="Total test time in seconds">73</TotalTime>
                <AutoTime name="Total automation time in seconds">73</AutoTime>
                <IdleTime name="Total idle/wait time in seconds">0</IdleTime>
                <TestResult name="Use INCOMPLETE PASS FAIL SKIP.">PASS</TestResult>
                <FailDesc name="Description of failure">COMPLETE</FailDesc>
            </Test3>
            <Test4>
                <StartTime name="Start date and time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss.">20161221:192340</StartTime>
                <TotalTime name="Total test time in seconds">1</TotalTime>
                <AutoTime name="Total automation time in seconds">1</AutoTime>
                <IdleTime name="Total idle/wait time in seconds">0</IdleTime>
                <TestResult name="Use INCOMPLETE PASS FAIL SKIP.">PASS</TestResult>
                <FailDesc name="Description of failure">COMPLETE</FailDesc>
            </Test4>
            <Test5>
                <StartTime name="Start date and time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss.">20161221:192341</StartTime>
                <TotalTime name="Total test time in seconds">1550</TotalTime>
                <AutoTime name="Total automation time in seconds">1550</AutoTime>
                <IdleTime name="Total idle/wait time in seconds">0</IdleTime>
                <TestResult name="Use INCOMPLETE PASS FAIL SKIP.">FAIL</TestResult>
                <FailDesc name="Description of failure">Failed Test5</FailDesc>
            </Test5>
            <Test6>
                <StartTime name="Start date and time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss."/>
                <TotalTime name="Total test time in seconds"/>
                <AutoTime name="Total automation time in seconds"/>
                <IdleTime name="Total idle/wait time in seconds"/>
                <TestResult name="Use INCOMPLETE PASS FAIL SKIP.">NOT RUN</TestResult>
                <FailDesc name="Description of failure"/>
            </Test6>
            <Test7>
                <StartTime name="Start date and time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss."/>
                <TotalTime name="Total test time in seconds"/>
                <AutoTime name="Total automation time in seconds"/>
                <IdleTime name="Total idle/wait time in seconds"/>
                <TestResult name="Use INCOMPLETE PASS FAIL SKIP.">NOT RUN</TestResult>
                <FailDesc name="Description of failure"/>
            </Test7>
            <Test8>
                <StartTime name="Start date and time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss."/>
                <TotalTime name="Total test time in seconds"/>
                <AutoTime name="Total automation time in seconds"/>
                <IdleTime name="Total idle/wait time in seconds"/>
                <TestResult name="Use INCOMPLETE PASS FAIL SKIP.">NOT RUN</TestResult>
                <FailDesc name="Description of failure"/>
            </Test8>
            <Test9>
                <StartTime name="Start date and time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss."/>
                <TotalTime name="Total test time in seconds"/>
                <AutoTime name="Total automation time in seconds"/>
                <IdleTime name="Total idle/wait time in seconds"/>
                <TestResult name="Use INCOMPLETE PASS FAIL SKIP.">NOT RUN</TestResult>
                <FailDesc name="Description of failure"/>
            </Test9>
            <Test10>
                <StartTime name="Start date and time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss."/>
                <TotalTime name="Total test time in seconds"/>
                <AutoTime name="Total automation time in seconds"/>
                <IdleTime name="Total idle/wait time in seconds"/>
                <TestResult name="Use INCOMPLETE PASS FAIL SKIP.">NOT RUN</TestResult>
                <FailDesc name="Description of failure"/>
            </Test10>
        </TestList>
    </TestInstance1>
    <TestInstance2>
        <LogFile>sample1.log</LogFile>
        <TSVFile>sample1.tsv</TSVFile>
        <TesterID>Me</TesterID>
        <Station>DEV01</Station>
        <ReleaseVersion>Rel_I02</ReleaseVersion>
        <StartTime name="Test Execution Start Date and Time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss">20161227:003807</StartTime>
        <EndTime name="Test Execution End Date and Time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss">20161227:035645</EndTime>
        <TotalTime name="Test Execution Total Time HH:mm:ss">3:18:38</TotalTime>
        <AutoTime name="Test Automation Total Time HH:mm:ss">3:18:38</AutoTime>
        <IdleTime name="Test Idle/Wait Total Time HH:mm:ss">0:00:00</IdleTime>
        <Status name="Test Execution Status.  Use IMCOMPLETE,PASS,FAIL">PASS</Status>
        <TestList>
            <Test1>
                <StartTime name="Start date and time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss.">20161227:003808</StartTime>
                <TotalTime name="Total test time in seconds">0</TotalTime>
                <AutoTime name="Total automation time in seconds">0</AutoTime>
                <IdleTime name="Total idle/wait time in seconds">0</IdleTime>
                <TestResult name="Use INCOMPLETE PASS FAIL SKIP.">PASS</TestResult>
                <FailDesc name="Description of failure">COMPLETE</FailDesc>
            </Test1>
            <Test2>
                <StartTime name="Start date and time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss.">20161227:003809</StartTime>
                <TotalTime name="Total test time in seconds">0</TotalTime>
                <AutoTime name="Total automation time in seconds">0</AutoTime>
                <IdleTime name="Total idle/wait time in seconds">0</IdleTime>
                <TestResult name="Use INCOMPLETE PASS FAIL SKIP.">PASS</TestResult>
                <FailDesc name="Description of failure">COMPLETE</FailDesc>
            </Test2>
            <Test3>
                <StartTime name="Start date and time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss.">20161227:003809</StartTime>
                <TotalTime name="Total test time in seconds">89</TotalTime>
                <AutoTime name="Total automation time in seconds">89</AutoTime>
                <IdleTime name="Total idle/wait time in seconds">0</IdleTime>
                <TestResult name="Use INCOMPLETE PASS FAIL SKIP.">PASS</TestResult>
                <FailDesc name="Description of failure">COMPLETE</FailDesc>
            </Test3>
            <Test4>
                <StartTime name="Start date and time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss.">20161227:003938</StartTime>
                <TotalTime name="Total test time in seconds">496</TotalTime>
                <AutoTime name="Total automation time in seconds">16</AutoTime>
                <IdleTime name="Total idle/wait time in seconds">480</IdleTime>
                <TestResult name="Use INCOMPLETE PASS FAIL SKIP.">PASS</TestResult>
                <FailDesc name="Description of failure">COMPLETE</FailDesc>
            </Test4>
            <Test5>
                <StartTime name="Start date and time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss.">20161227:004754</StartTime>
                <TotalTime name="Total test time in seconds">144</TotalTime>
                <AutoTime name="Total automation time in seconds">144</AutoTime>
                <IdleTime name="Total idle/wait time in seconds">0</IdleTime>
                <TestResult name="Use INCOMPLETE PASS FAIL SKIP.">PASS</TestResult>
                <FailDesc name="Description of failure">COMPLETE</FailDesc>
            </Test5>
            <Test6>
                <StartTime name="Start date and time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss.">20161227:005018</StartTime>
                <TotalTime name="Total test time in seconds">1</TotalTime>
                <AutoTime name="Total automation time in seconds">1</AutoTime>
                <IdleTime name="Total idle/wait time in seconds">0</IdleTime>
                <TestResult name="Use INCOMPLETE PASS FAIL SKIP.">PASS</TestResult>
                <FailDesc name="Description of failure">COMPLETE</FailDesc>
            </Test6>
            <Test7>
                <StartTime name="Start date and time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss.">20161227:005019</StartTime>
                <TotalTime name="Total test time in seconds">40</TotalTime>
                <AutoTime name="Total automation time in seconds">40</AutoTime>
                <IdleTime name="Total idle/wait time in seconds">0</IdleTime>
                <TestResult name="Use INCOMPLETE PASS FAIL SKIP.">PASS</TestResult>
                <FailDesc name="Description of failure">COMPLETE</FailDesc>
            </Test7>
            <Test8>
                <StartTime name="Start date and time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss.">20161227:005059</StartTime>
                <TotalTime name="Total test time in seconds">719</TotalTime>
                <AutoTime name="Total automation time in seconds">599</AutoTime>
                <IdleTime name="Total idle/wait time in seconds">120</IdleTime>
                <TestResult name="Use INCOMPLETE PASS FAIL SKIP.">PASS</TestResult>
                <FailDesc name="Description of failure">COMPLETE</FailDesc>
            </Test8>
            <Test9>
                <StartTime name="Start date and time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss.">20161227:010258</StartTime>
                <TotalTime name="Total test time in seconds">531</TotalTime>
                <AutoTime name="Total automation time in seconds">111</AutoTime>
                <IdleTime name="Total idle/wait time in seconds">420</IdleTime>
                <TestResult name="Use INCOMPLETE PASS FAIL SKIP.">PASS</TestResult>
                <FailDesc name="Description of failure">COMPLETE</FailDesc>
            </Test9>
            <Test10>
                <StartTime name="Start date and time YYYYMMDD:HHmmss.">20161227:011149</StartTime>
                <TotalTime name="Total test time in seconds">396</TotalTime>
                <AutoTime name="Total automation time in seconds">396</AutoTime>
                <IdleTime name="Total idle/wait time in seconds">0</IdleTime>
                <TestResult name="Use INCOMPLETE PASS FAIL SKIP.">PASS</TestResult>
                <FailDesc name="Description of failure">COMPLETE</FailDesc>
            </Test10>
        </TestList>
    </TestInstance2>
</SYSTEM>"
```

Existing XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:key name="keyTestInstanceID" match="*[(contains(name(), 'TestInstance'))]" use="." />
    <xsl:key name="instances" match="TotalTime" use="@name"/>
    <xsl:key name="testinstances" match="TotalTime" use="@name"/>
    <xsl:key name="timeStamps" match="EndTime" use="@name"/>
<xsl:template match="SYSTEM">
    <HTML>
        <HEAD>
            <TITLE></TITLE>
        </HEAD>
        <!-- BODY tag variables used to save the page scroll position -->
        <BODY onScroll="document.cookie='ypos=' + window.pageYOffset" onLoad="window.scrollTo(0,readCookie('ypos'))">

            <H1><xsl:value-of select="XMLfile"/></H1>
                <div class="hr"><hr></hr></div>
                <div class="hr2"><span>New Test History</span></div> 
                <xsl:for-each select="./*">
                    <xsl:if test="starts-with(local-name(), 'TestInstance')">
                        <xsl:value-of select="[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('keyTestInstanceID', substring(.,13))[1])]"/>
                        <p><b><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></b></p>
                        <p><xsl:value-of select="substring(local-name(),13)" /></p>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <div class="hr"><hr></hr></div>
                <div class="hr2"><span>Old Test History</span></div>
                <xsl:for-each select="./*">
                    <xsl:if test="starts-with(local-name(), 'TestInstance')">
                        <p><b><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></b></p>

                        <div id="tit">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                        </div>

                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
        </BODY>
    </HTML>
</xsl:template>
<!-- Test Instance Template -->
<xsl:template match="*[(contains(name(), 'TestInstance'))]">
    <!-- Using "instances" key previously defined, store the total test time (seconds) in a variable named "pSum" -->
    <xsl:variable name="pSum"><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('instances', 'Total test time in seconds')[text()])" /></xsl:variable>
    <div id="tirh">
        <div id="ticl1">
            Test Name
        </div>
        <div id="ticl2">
            Total (sec)
        </div>
        <div id="ticl3">
            Auto (sec)
        </div>
        <div id="ticl4">
            Idle (sec)
        </div>
        <div id="ticl5">
            Result
        </div>
    </div>
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <!-- Test Instance Statistics -->
        <xsl:if test="starts-with(local-name(), 'TestList')">
            <!-- Using "testinstances" key previously defined, store the total test time (seconds) in a variable named "tSum" -->
            <xsl:variable name="tSum"><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('testinstances', 'Total test time in seconds')[text()])" /></xsl:variable>
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <div id="tir">
                    <div id="ticl1">
                        <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="ticl2">
                        <xsl:value-of select="./TotalTime" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="ticl3">
                        <xsl:value-of select="./AutoTime" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="ticl4">
                        <xsl:value-of select="./IdleTime" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="ticl5">
                        <xsl:value-of select="./TestResult" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <!-- Test Instance Time -->
            <div id="tir">
                <div id="ticl1">
                    <b>Sub Total Test Time </b>(HH:MM:SS) 
                </div>
                <div id="ticl2">
                    <xsl:if test="not(string-length(../TotalTime))=0">
                        <b><xsl:value-of select="../TotalTime" /></b>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="(string-length(../TotalTime))=0">
                        <b><xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number(floor($tSum div 3600),'00'), ':', format-number(floor($tSum mod 3600 div 60),'00'), ':', format-number($tSum mod 60,'00'))"/></b>
                    </xsl:if>
                </div>
                <div id="ticl3">
                </div>
                <div id="ticl4">
                </div>
                <div id="ticl5">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Total Test Time (reformated from variable $pSum) -->
            <div id="tir">
                <div id="ticl1">
                    <b>Total Test Time </b>(HH:MM:SS) 
                </div>
                <div id="ticl2">
                    <b><xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number(floor($pSum div 3600),'00'), ':', format-number(floor($pSum mod 3600 div 60),'00'), ':', format-number($pSum mod 60,'00'))"/></b>
                </div>
                <div id="ticl3">
                </div>
                <div id="ticl4">
                </div>
                <div id="ticl5">
                </div>
            </div>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>"
```

GOAL:
for each TestInstance[#]:
Display all TotalTime values and TestResult in rows.
Sum all TotalTime values and display as Sub Total Test Time (HH:MM:SS).
Each TestInstance[#] also displays a running total as Total Test Time (HH:MM:SS) where TestInstance0 total is equal to Sub Total Test Time.
Sum each additional TestInstance[#] the same as above but each new Total Test Time (HH:MM:SS) displays  ((Sub Total Test Time of TestInstance[N])+(Sub Total Test Time of TestInstance[N-1])).

Example:

```
Old Test History
TestInstance0
...
Sub Total Test Time (HH:MM:SS) 1:07:27
Total Test Time (HH:MM:SS) 1:07:27

TestInstance1
...
Sub Total Test Time (HH:MM:SS) 0:27:06
Total Test Time (HH:MM:SS) 1:34:33 

TestInstance2
...
Sub Total Test Time (HH:MM:SS) 3:18:38
Total Test Time (HH:MM:SS) 4:53:11
```

I am struggling with how to assign variables for sub total test time and total test time and then get separate sub totals and a running total test time.
I attempted to use similar examples without success. One in particular was 
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1849/grouping-xml-using-xslt

Comment: You must show us the desired HTML output, not some rendered interpretation.

Comment: These numbers do not add up: your `TestInstance0` has a `TotalTime` of `1:07:27`, but summing the `Test#/TotalTime` values only gives `01:07:26`. With `TestInstance1` it's  `0:27:06` vs. `00:27:04`, and `TestInstance2` has a major gap of `3:18:38` vs. `00:40:16`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you.  It creates lookup data with the running totals.  Use it to lookup the running totals.  You can use this lookup data instead of the keys elsewhere in your code, if you want.

```
<!-- Create some meta data. Use this to look up the running total based on the 
     node-id(.) of a TestInstance
 -->
<xsl:variable name="test">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//Test1|//Test2|//Test3|//Test4|//Test5|//Test6|//Test7|//Test8|//Test9|//Test10" mode="metadata"/>
</xsl:variable>

<!--  Only use node-set for version 1.0. -->
<xsl:variable name="testList" select="msxml:node-set($test)"/>

<!-- Mode to create elements that contain the metadata. -->
<xsl:template match="//Test1|//Test2|//Test3|//Test4|//Test5|//Test6|//Test7|//Test8|//Test9|//Test10" mode="metadata">
  <xsl:element name="element">
    <xsl:element name="id">
      <xsl:value-of select="generate-id(.)"/>
    </xsl:element> 
    <xsl:element name="TestInstanceID">
      <!-- Get the TestInstance. -->
      <xsl:value-of select="generate-id(../..)"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="TestListID">
      <!-- Get the TestInstance. -->
      <xsl:value-of select="generate-id(..)"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="TotalTime">
      <xsl:call-template name="getCleanNumber">
        <xsl:with-param name="inNumStr" select="TotalTime"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Get a distinct list of TestInstanceID's. -->
<xsl:variable name="distinctTestInstanceIDs">
  <xsl:copy-of select="$testList/element[not(TestInstanceID=preceding-sibling::element/TestInstanceID)]"/>
</xsl:variable>

<!--  Only use node-set for version 1.0. -->
<xsl:variable name="distinctTestInstanceIDsList" select="msxml:node-set($distinctTestInstanceIDs)"/>

<!-- Group the metadata based on distinctTestInstanceIDs. -->
<xsl:variable name="groupedTestInstance">
  <xsl:for-each select="$distinctTestInstanceIDsList/element/TestInstanceID">
    <xsl:variable name="TestInstanceID" select="."/>
    <xsl:element name="element">
      <xsl:element name="TestInstanceID">
        <!-- Get the TestInstance. -->
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="TotalTime">
        <xsl:value-of select="sum($testList/element[TestInstanceID=$TestInstanceID]/TotalTime)"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<!--  Only use node-set for version 1.0. -->
<xsl:variable name="groupedTestInstanceList" select="msxml:node-set($groupedTestInstance)"/>


<!-- Now create the rolling totals. -->
<xsl:variable name="rollingTotals">
  <xsl:call-template name="generateRollingTotals">
    <xsl:with-param name="index" select="1"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="rollingTotal" select="0"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>

<!--  Only use node-set for version 1.0. -->
<xsl:variable name="rollingTotalsList" select="msxml:node-set($rollingTotals)"/>

<!-- Use the rollingTotalsList to lookup the rolling total for a TestInstance.

     Create a variable the contains the node-id of the TextIntance for which you 
     want the rolling total.

     <xsl:variable name="TestInstanceID" select="generate-id(.)"/>  etc.

    Use this variable for the lookup.

-->

<!-- Recursive template to create rolling totals. -->
<xsl:template name="generateRollingTotals">
  <xsl:param name="index"/>
  <xsl:param name="rollingTotal"/>

  <xsl:if test="$index &lt;= count($groupedTestInstanceList/element)">
    <xsl:element name="element">
      <xsl:element name="TestInstanceID">
        <!-- Get the TestInstance. -->
        <xsl:value-of select="$groupedTestInstanceList/element[$index]/TestInstanceID"/>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="rollingTotalTime">
        <xsl:value-of select="$groupedTestInstanceList/element[$index]/TotalTime + $rollingTotal"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>

    <xsl:call-template name="generateRollingTotals">
      <xsl:with-param name="index" select="$index + 1"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="rollingTotal" select="$groupedTestInstanceList/element[$index]/TotalTime + $rollingTotal"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="getCleanNumber">
  <xsl:param name="inNumStr"/>
  <!-- Clean up the number.  Get the digits and decimal point only. -->
  <xsl:variable name="rawNum" select="translate($inNumStr,translate($inNumStr,'0123456789.',''),'')"/>
  <!-- Get the number. -->
  <xsl:variable name="num">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$rawNum='' or $rawNum=0">
        <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="contains($inNumStr,'-') or contains($inNumStr,'(')">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('-',$rawNum)"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$rawNum"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="$num"/>
</xsl:template>
```